# C Print string from a particular character

Tags: c

I am trying to extract relative path name from absolute path name. Is there a function for this in C? Is there a function to print string starting from a particular character(I have the index)?

Comment: You can add the index to print from there. [See here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/311f96ccf5f8bd2d66d195009dfd186c). I'm not sure about any function to do it.

Comment: If you have the index of the / can't u just use strncpy or are you for some reason trying to void using a separate copy / buffer?

Comment: Thanks Troy but 'strncpy' would not work for me. I want the characters after '/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the index you can do it quite easily.

```
char * src = "YOUR STRING";
char * dst; // destination
dst = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char) * 20);
dst = (char *)memcpy(dst, &src[THE_INDEX_YOU_KNOW], strlen(src)-THE_INDEX_YOU_KNOW);
dst[len-start]='\0';
```

Answer (score 2):

In POSIX.1-2001 (e.g. Linux), `man 3 basename` gives:

> > The  functions dirname() and basename() break a null-terminated pathname string into directory and filename components. In the usual case,  ... basename() returns the component following the final '/'.  Trailing '/' characters are not counted as part of the pathname.

Comment: What if it's in a subdirectory?

Comment: Doesn't extract a relative pathname, extracts the ... basename! What about all the other possible relative paths?

Comment: @Troy: Point taken. With both hard links and soft links, and mount points, I don't think there is an easy solution in Unix to the question "What is the shortest path from here to there?".

Answer (score 0):

As joseph mentioned, you can use basename().

Hope the following program helps a bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( int argc, char **  argv)
{
  char *path = "/Users/lionnew/cpgm";
  printf ("%s\n", basename (path));

  /* If you have an index */

  int index =15;
  int len = strlen(path);
  char * dest = malloc(len+1);
  dest[len] = '\0';

  strcpy (dest, (path+index));
  printf ("\n Destination String %s ", dest);

}
```

NOTE: Make sure your index value is not geater than the string len to avoid segmentation fault.

Hope this helps to some extend. ;)